# vim complete() with result from lvim

Tags: python, vim, macvim

I am trying to create a function that will pop up a list of  file includes the word "Module"(case insensitive).

I tried :lvim /Module/gj *.f90 when all *.f90 is in current dir, but I failed to make a globpath() like expand so that I can include and subdirs.

So, I turned to python. From python, I am getting the list perfectly. I am inserting the python code, which will possibly show my goal:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re
flsts = []
path = "/home/rudra/Devel/dream/"
print("All files==>")
for dirs, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for tfile in files:
        if tfile.endswith('f90'):
            print(os.path.splitext(tfile)[0])
            text = open(dirs+'/'+tfile).read()
            match = re.search("Module", text)
            if match:
                flsts.append(os.path.splitext(tfile)[0])
print("The list to be used ==>")
print(flsts)
```

after having the list, I want a

```
complete(col('.')), flsts)
```

The problem is, I am unable to include it inside vim function.

May I kindly have some help, so that I can get a list from vim and use it in the complete function?

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234394/selecting-resulting-files-from-grep-in-vim) as a possible solution, but unfortunately it is not.
Kindly help.

**edit: More explanation**
So, say, in my work-dir, i have:

```
$tree */*.f90
OLD/dirac.f90
OLD/environment.f90
src/constants.f90
src/gencrystal.f90
src/geninp.f90
src/init.f90
```

among them, only two has word `module` in it:

```
$ grep Module */*.f90
OLD/dirac.f90:      10 :module mdirac
src/constants.f90:   2 :module constants
```

So, I want, with a `inoremap`, `complete()` to pop up only `constants` and `dirac`.

Hence, `Module` is the `keyword` I am searching in the `subdirs` of present working directory, and only those file matches (dirac and constants in this example) should pop up in `complete()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your exact problem is.

With `split(globpath('./**/Module/**', '*.f90'), '\n')` you will obtain the list of all files that match `*.f90`, and which are somewhere within a directory named `Module`.

Then, using `complete()` has a few restrictions. It has to be from a function that will be called from insert mode, and that returns an empty string.

By itself, `complete()` will insert the selected text, if we play with the `{starcol}` parameter, we can even remove what's before the cursor. This way, you can type `Module`, hit the key you want and use Module to filter.

```
function! s:Complete()
  " From lh-vim-lib: word_tools.vim
  let key = GetCurrentKeyword()
  let files = split(glob('./**/*'.key.'*/**', '*.vim'), '\n')
  call complete(col('.')-len(key), files )
  return ''
endfunction

inoremap µ <c-R>=<sid>Complete()<cr>
```

However, if you want to trigger an action (instead of inserting text), it becomes much more complex. I did that in [muTemplate](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate). I've published the framework used to associate hooks to completion items in [lh-vim-lib](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhVimLib) (See `lh#icomplete#*()` functions).

EDIT: OK, then, I'll work with `let files=split(system("grep --include=*.f90 -Ril module *"), '\n')` to obtain the list of files, then call `complete(col('.'), files)` with that list. That should be the more efficient solution. This is somehow quite similar to Ingo's solution. The difference is that we don't need Python if grep is available.

Regarding Python integration, well it's possible with `:py vim.command()`. See for instance jira-complete that integrates `complete()` with a Python script that builds the completion-list: https://github.com/mnpk/vim-jira-complete/blob/master/autoload/jira.vim#L116

Notes:

- if "module:" can be pre-searched with ctags, it will to possible to extract your files from tags database with `taglist()`.
- It's also possible to fill dynamically the list of files with `complete_add()`, which is something that would make sense from a python script that tests each file one after the other.

Comment: Hi @Luc, I have not managed to make your snippet run, but I have added more explanation in the question. May you kindly have a look?

Comment: OK. I've added a second part to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example at `:help complete()` that you can adapt. If you modify your Python script to output just the (newline-separated) files, you can invoke it via `system()`:

```
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=FindFiles()<CR>

function! FindFiles()
  call complete(col('.'), split(system('python path/to/script.py'), '\n'))
  return ''
endfunction
```

Comment: correct...thanks for showing. But this is not what I am looking for, unless I make it solve today.
Right now, I am hoping for either embedding python into vim, or do it in pure viml.
But, thaks for your suggestion...I will keep that as backup :)